# Sidebar disappears when scrolled to top

Tags: jquery, css, sidebar, scrolltop

I'm working on this site right now where I made sidebar follow until I hit footer.

[DEMO SITE](http://1ne-studio.com/test/2/)
ID : test PASS : 2015

I made that work fine, but when I scroll back to top(very top), my side bar will hide it self.

[image: side bar disappears...]

When I scroll back little bit down or click F5 and refresh it will appear again.

Here's the javascript I used for this function.

```
$(function(){
var target = $("#subContainer");//select which element you want to follow
var footer = $("footer")//making sidebar stop at footer
var targetHeight = target.outerHeight(true);
var targetTop = target.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > targetTop){
        var footerTop = footer.offset().top;

        if(scrollTop + targetHeight > footerTop){
            customTopPosition = footerTop - (scrollTop + targetHeight)
            target.css({position: "fixed", top:  customTopPosition + "px"});
        }else{
            target.css({position: "fixed", top: "10px"});
        }
    }else{
        target.css({position: "static", top: "auto"});
    }
});
```

});

How could I fix this problem so that sidebar will be shown when I scroll right back up.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: do you have any code for that?

Comment: @SoursopTree Yes I added the code above thanks!!

Comment: I am sorry, I mean revert its style back to default using this: `target.removeAttr("style");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
target.css({position: "static", top: "auto"});
```

Just reset the top css back to 0px:

```
target.css({top: "0px"});
```

This is because your original style on #subContainer already had `position: fixed` when we first load the page. So really the only thing changing is the top position value.

You should be able to simplify your code further by only change top:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > targetTop){
        var footerTop = footer.offset().top;

        if(scrollTop + targetHeight > footerTop){
            customTopPosition = footerTop - (scrollTop + targetHeight)
            target.css({top:  customTopPosition + "px"});
        }else{
            target.css({ top: "10px"});
        }
    }else{
        target.css({top: "0px"});
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the further guidance!!! I decided to simplify what SoursopTree gave us with your code!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to revert its style back to default when the page scroll is reaching the top of your page. This solution can be used to solve the problem in that case.

Replace your codes above with this:

```
$(function(){
var target = $("#subContainer");//select which element you want to follow
var footer = $("footer")//making sidebar stop at footer
var targetHeight = target.outerHeight(true);
var targetTop = target.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > targetTop){
        var footerTop = footer.offset().top;

        if(scrollTop + targetHeight > footerTop){
            customTopPosition = footerTop - (scrollTop + targetHeight)
            target.css({position: "fixed", top:  customTopPosition + "px"});
        }else{
            target.css({position: "fixed", top: "10px"});
        }
    }else{
        target.removeAttr("style"); // change is made here
    }
});

});
```

Comment: thank you for your help! very fast response and exactly what I needed!